# iOS Simulator is not using the full screen to display my controls after navigating

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2019

I have a pretty simple UI.  Master Detail Layout with Menu Page and some Detail Pages that get you to drill into more Detail.

When running in debug mode from Visual Studio to the Simulator on the Mac, I am seeing some weird behavior.

Page 1 is the 1st Page displayed "Properties".  On first load it loads correctly.  I then select the Menu and go to "Tenants" Page.  You can see that the List View does not EXPAND the same way it did on the "Properties" Page.

When I go BACK to the "Properties" Page, it has the same Weird Behavior and does not EXPAND.[Link to Picture of my Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrDaR.jpg)

Comment: If I stop and start the simulator, and then run the simulator outside of visual studio my app behaves as expected.  Are the any known issues or settings I can look at to have it work when launched from Visual Studio?

Comment: That is very strange, it doesn't seem normal. Are you using any special libraries? Can you share some of your listview code? Are you using Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Native iOS?

Comment: @thinkjohn Do you mean that not works as expected when starting with visual studio ? Suggesting that set a background color for `ListView` to check its size whether changed.

Comment: Show your XAML or Code so we can see what wrong

Comment: I don't have the XAML.  It is all done in code.

Comment: I changed the color of the ListView and you can the behavior in my original picture.  The ListView fills the screen and then on the second load you can see the GRAY area underneath the ListView.

Comment: @thinkjohn Okey, It seems that the listview of the Properties page is affected by the listw size of the Tenants page.The cell of the listview used by these two pages is a template, and whether some processing is done when the interface is switched.If possible, sharing a sample project is helpful to find the reason.